# Definition of monoidal category without set theory and without assuming small categories

Tags: category-theory, definition, monoidal-categories

**I am interested in finding a definition of monoidal category that ultimately relies only on category theory elements such as objects, arrows, and categories. For instance, it should never assume we are talking about small categories because that relies on what a set is.**

From [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage), I get that the tensor product is a functor. Then, for the definition of functor, there are two options. The first options (external definition) says that a functor is a *mapping* satisfying some properties. Here, "mapping" seems to be relying on sets already, so I think I need to use the second definition.

The second definition (internal definition) says that a functor is a pair of morphisms in a category for which its target and source categories are internal categories. Finally, an internal category is defined as 2 objects and 4 morphisms from the ambient category satisfying a few properties.

*The problem is that I don't know how to put together this second definition of functor with what appears in the definition of monoidal category.*

The functor appearing the definition of monoidal category is $\otimes: C \times C \to C$, but since, in the definition using internal categories, I never see the category product $\times$ (which is to be expected, since internal categories don't appear inside the ambient category as single objects), I don't know how to put the definitions of functor and of monoidal category together.

Is such a definition even possible? I appreciate any help with this.

PS: Trying to answer this, I see in a few places mentions to 2-categories, but for these I also don't see a definition in terms only of category.

Comment: The definition of category itself relies on set theory, so I don't think it's quite clear what you're asking for.

Comment: A two-variable functor on an internal category $C$ can certainly be defined as an internal functor $C\times C\to C.$ I’m not clear what you’re worried about there.

Comment: @varkor Aren't there some foundational ideas where "category" is some kind of primitive notion, not defined through set theory?

Comment: If you have definitions of functor, natural transformation and category which you're happy with, it's easy to define a monoidal category. A monoidal category is just the data of a category, a functor, a distinguished "unit" object, three natural transformations (and two coherence diagrams which always have to be satisfied and people seem to ignore). If, in whatever foundation you're using, you're unable to encode such data, then that foundation is surely seriously flawed. To describe a tuple of things is incredibly basic

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. What do you exactly mean with "only in terms of category theory"? Are you looking for foundations in which categories, objects and morphisms are the primitive concepts? such foundations exist, but even they will have a category Set and axioms for it.

Comment: @varkor, as FShrike suggested, I would like to see the monoidal category resting on categorical foundations, as in using only metacategories.

Comment: @KevinArlin, if C is a internal category then as per the definition in nLab it is not given by a cincle object C, so I don't see how $C\times C$ makes sense.

Comment: @Nico the idea is not to forbid sets to exist, but to arrive at monoidal categories without using it, as described the 'metacategory' article in nLab. I am interested specifically in how an abstract "parallel" composition (the tensor) can be reduced to an abstract "sequential" composition (that is, $\circ$ associative with matching target/source as in a category).

Comment: @FShrike, the problem that I have is with how those definitions I mentioned play together, because as far as I understand them, each is given in a different context. The expression $C \times C$ in the def. of monoidal category seems to imply that $C$ is an object in a category where that product exists, but for the def. functors using only arrows/objects, the categories are internal categories, so they are not single objects inside the ambient category as per the definition of internal category.

Comment: @PauloCavalcanti: Mac Lane's notion of metacategory is still essentially set-theoretic; he simply permits the collection of objects and morphims to be larger than a set (i.e. a class). The definition of monoidal category does not require the category to be small, so there is no issue with the standard definition.

Comment: Do you want a short intro into foundations, inaccessible cardinals and how category theorists deal with size issues? The stuff you seem to have trouble with isn't really specific to category theory imo. category theory just happens to sit right at border of that what can be expressed in ZFC without introducing large cardinal axioms, which is where all this confusing talk about sets and classes comes from.

Comment: I don't think there is anything better than definition 2.1 on this nLab page. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category It doesn't get more "purely in terms of category theory" than that. Only functors objects and transformations are mentioned. The category $C\times C$ is a 2-product of $C$ with itself in the 2-category $Cat$ of categories (up to some size limit).

Comment: $C\times C$ is the product of $C$ with itself in the category of internal categories and internal functors. It’s no obstacle that $C$ happens to be formed of two objects in some other category. After all, an ordinary category is itself an internal category to the category of sets! Specifically if $C=(s,t:A\to B)$ then check that $C\times C=(s\times s,t\times t:A\times A\to B\times B).$

Comment: Ok, so to put the product in def. 2.1 from https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/product+category, together with def. 1 from https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category, can I just write, Obj($C$) as the object  (not necessarity set) $C_0$, Mor($C$) as $C_1$ and $\times$ as $\times_C$? I can see intuitively that this should be fine but not formally.